# WSO2 version 5.7 issue with multiple instance running

Tags: docker, wso2, wso2-identity-server

I am using wso2 version 5.7 in our product as identity server and consuming its all soap api almost like to create tenant in , to created user store in , to create service provider in as well claim also
 Now, Every things is working with single instance of wso2 means all the crud operation of the above operations.

Though, we are using docker on production env. whenever we are scaling up or down with wso2 node more than one then all the above operations some time work and some time not working mostly not working means i think the data in not sync properly with all the running node.

So please provide me solution for this.

Comment: Can you update with the error log which can be found in the /repository/logs folder during the time you observed issue? then it will be easy to help you out

Comment: Basically when  we added new claim its added successfully without any error, then go to wso2 console - go under claim to see my newly added claim then its not display over there. when we tried to edit same claim then throwing error there is no such a claim in wso2, but some time later we tried then the same claim does display on wso2 console as well as we can edit it.

Comment: Hence , I case of multiple instance or node of wso2 then the data is not sync properly

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue [1] and already fixed in the public branch. If you build the latest product from the source, this will be fixed. Or else, you can use WUM [2] to get this for IS 5.7.0.

[1] https://github.com/wso2/product-is/issues/5015

[2] https://wso2.com/updates/wum

Comment: we have upgrade the wso2 version with 5.8 , and now we are scalling the wso2 instance more than two or two. We are facing the same issue still. The issue is when we add claim using soap request the claim is added successfully on one of the wso2 instance. then go to wso2 login console some time the claim is displaying there some time not. means claim data is not syncing proper in case of multiple instance of wso2. Could you pls help me.